# How to recover OpenGL buffers after minimization?

Tags: opengl, windows-7, buffer, sdl

Assume I made an application that uses SDL + OpenGL to display graphics. The scene is not dynamic so I do the drawing and swapping of the buffers once in a while.

I observed that after minimization and bringing back of a window under Windows 7 the displayed content gets destroyed and random stuff is displayed. Is there any way I can recover it without repeating the last rendering?

I'm using Windows 7 Proffesional SP1 with Intel G45/G43 Express Chipset.

Comment: Why don't you render to texture in any case and then just draw a full-screen quad whenever you need to with the rendered texture?

Comment: Well, I am aware that this can be easily solved by using intermediate buffer, but I was wondering if this could be made without repeating the rendering **nor copying the whole buffer** which I should've mentioned.

It's hard to explain why I wanted this. The problem was completely made out because what I really am doing was too complicated to tell.

After some additional research I now know that my expectations were unrealistic and I have either do the first or the latter thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could copy it to a texture (with `glCopyTexSubImage2D`), and then render that texture when you need to display stuff. Or you could render to a texture to begin with via FBOs.

But there is no automatic way to recover the image data. Really, it'd be easier to just re-render the display when it is restored. You may have the same problem if a window overlaps the display.